# Problema javascript array

Tags: javascript, array

estou enfrentando um problema com array javascript.
Estou utilizando o Google Charts e para popular o gráfico, é necessário um array contendo o nome e a participação.

```
function contentChart(){
var id = document.querySelectorAll('.id')
var nome = document.querySelectorAll('.nome')
var sobrenome = document.querySelectorAll('.sobrenome')
var participacao = document.querySelectorAll('.participacao')

var chartContent = [];
for (i = 0; i < id.length ; i++) {
    chartContent += `['${nome[i].innerText} ${sobrenome[i].innerText}', ${participacao[i].innerText}],`;
    /*var result = chartContent.push([`${nome[i].innerText} ${sobrenome[i].innerText}`, participacao[i].innerText],)*/
}
return chartContent }
```

A função acima cria uma variável e atribui os valores obtidos, dando quase certo. Porém, por retornar uma string dá error.

```
Retorno : "['carlos alberto', 1],['bahia folia', 2],"
```

Se vinhesse sem as aspas daria certo.

ex: `['carlos alberto', 1],['bahia folia', 2],`

> Error: jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:178 Uncaught (in promise)
>   Error: Invalid row #1
>       at Object.gvjs_ql [as arrayToDataTable] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:178)
>       at drawChart (main.js:9)

Comment: Na linha comentada está do jeito certo, só remover a última "," do final. Só que não tem o porquê de criar uma variável, só fazer o `push` e deu

Comment: Agora retorna um array com dois arrays. (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]

Comment: Se não é esse o objetivo, qual é?

Comment: Retornar arrays separado por vírgula:    ['carlos alberto', 1],['bahia folia', 2],

Comment: Então o que você quer uma string com um JSON de um array bidimensional? Se é isso a forma como fez está quase correta, basta trocar as aspas simples (') por duplas (")

Answer (score 1):

Olha, não sei bem o que queres fazer, mas tem duas possibilidades que imaginei.
Preservar o conteúdo do **chartContent** e utilizar a função **eval**.
Mas deveria preservar o tipo da variável como **Array** e não transformando ela em um **String**.

**Código alterado:**

```
for (i = 0; i < id.length ; i++) {
    chartContent.push(eval(`['${nome[i].innerText} ${sobrenome[i].innerText}', ${participacao[i].innerText}],`));
}
```

**Mas recomendo esta forma:**

```
function contentChart() {
       const id = document.querySelectorAll('.id');
       const nome = document.querySelectorAll('.nome');
       const sobrenome = document.querySelectorAll('.sobrenome');
       const participacao = document.querySelectorAll('.participacao');

       return id.map((valor, i) => [`${nome[i].innerText} ${sobrenome[i].innerText}`, participacao[i].innerText]);
}
```

**Considerações:**

1. Coloquei **const** porque as variáveis são imutáveis;
2. Em vez do **for**, inseri o **map**. Ele é mais elegante e mais rápido que o **forEach**;
3. Pelo que percebi a *participação* é sempre **number**, então retirei as aspas.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Pode até ser mais elegante, mas é impossível que o `map` seja mais rápido que o `for`, haja vista que, a grosso modo, um `map` é implementado a partir de um `for`.

Comment: Fato, editei minha resposta. Valeus.